# How to assign JSON body to Boost Library 1.70 http::request as POST request?

Tags: c++, rest, http, boost

I am new to the Boost library. I try to create an Rest HTTP request using the Boost::http library.
My question is how can i simply assign the JSON payload to the http request.

the following code snippet shows my current try which connects successfully but the payload is not assigned.

```
http::request<http::string_body> req{ http::verb::post, LOGIN_PATH, 10 };
req.set(beast::http::field::content_type, "application/json");
req.body() = std::move(serviceUser);

// Send the HTTP request to the remote host
http::write(stream, req);
// This buffer is used for reading and must be persisted
beast::flat_buffer buffer;

// Declare a container to hold the response
http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;

// Receive the HTTP response
http::read(stream, buffer, res);

// Write the message to standard out
std::cout << res << std::endl;

return "OK";
```

The following snippet shows the JSON message.

```
std::stringstream strStream;
        
strStream << "{\"userName\" : lena, \"password\" : liebe }";
serviceUser = strStream.str();
```

Can you give me a simple example please. Importent to mention is that i use the Boost library version 1.70.

Comment: I think you need to call the `prepare_payload()` method before sending the request, from the documentation: "This function will adjust the Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding field values based on the properties of the body."

Comment: You can probably add the `Content-Length` header yourself, but I recommend using the library method as it does not only the length but also the encoding, it might also do some body related stuff in the background. The `Content-Length` header is required by specification, if it's ommited but the body is sent, the receiving side usually ignores the body so the request wouldn't work anyways. And the boost library probably ignores the body of the message when sending (it probably sends only N bytes of the body to save throughput, taking N from the header, default is probably 0 then)